# Recursion in SBCL

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, tail-recursion, sbcl

I am having an issue with SBCL (on linux) which might be related to tail recursion (not that I'm entirely sure what that is).  I am adding the code this time (it looks long but that's because I stretched it all out).

The deal is that I have a function 'compare-pstructs' which compares two structures.  The structures, however, may have a list of those same structures as a component.  Naturally, this begs for a recursive solution.

A second function 'compare-parses' is called when the above function needs to compare a list of these pstructs.  Naturally, the compare-parses function must appeal to the compare-pstructs function again to compare the individual pstructs.

So, it is supposed to bounce back and forth between these functions building up the stack frames and then pop them off as it discovers individual pstructs do or don't match and do the same as whole parses are discovered to match or not.

What actually takes place is that the first time a stack frame is popped, no more recursive calls take place.  Stranger yet, the loop that walks down the list of pstructs (in the compare-parses function) continues to iterate, only executing the code below the callback to the compare-pstructs function.

I am going to try combine these into one function, but still, I wonder why it doesn't work as two.

The code follows along with a log.  Thanks for looking out, everybody.

-Todd

```
(defstruct pstruct
    syntactic-info  ;; A list
    dependents  ;; A list of more pstructs
 )

(defun compare-parses (p1t  p2t)
(defparameter idx  0)
(defparameter max-idx (length p1t))

;; If they're not the same length, all bets are off.
(if     (not 
        (equal 
            (length p1t)
            (length p2t)
        )
    )
        (return-from compare-parses NIL)    
)
(loop
    (print "idx before compare pstructs:")
    (print idx)
    (if
        (null (compare-pstructs (nth idx p1t) (nth idx p2t)))
            (return-from compare-parses NIL)
    )
    (setf idx (1+ idx))
    (print "Added one to idx:")
    (print idx)
    (if (>= idx max-idx)
        (return)
    ) 
)
(return-from compare-parses T)
)

(defun compare-pstructs (p1 p2)
(print "P1")
(print p1)
(print "P2")
(print p2)

(if     (not (equal (pstruct-syntactic-info p1)     (pstruct-syntactic-info p2)))
        (return-from compare-pstructs NIL)
)
(if     (and
        (null (pstruct-dependents p1))  
        (null (pstruct-dependents p2))
    )
    (return-from compare-pstructs T)
)
(if     (and
        (not (null (pstruct-dependents p1)))    
        (not (null (pstruct-dependents p2)))
    )
    (return-from compare-pstructs 
        (compare-parses
            (pstruct-dependents p1) (pstruct-dependents p2)
        )
    )
)
;; If one or the other (not both) dependents is NIL then return NIL.
(return-from compare-pstructs NIL)
)

;; Two structures for test data (notice one has an "X" stuck in it
;; to make the two different.

(defparameter x2
 '#S(PSTRUCT
 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Sfin")
 :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Ext" "NP" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "S"
                                  "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                 :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON"
                                                  "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S"
                                                  "Sin1" "1st" "Sin"
                                                  "NomC")
                                 :DEPENDENTS NIL)))
              #S(PSTRUCT
                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Plu" "Sin2" "Sin3" "Sin1" "Pres" "V"
                                  "Trans_V" "TransComp_V" "Intrans_V"  
                                  "Ditrans_V" "Inf")
                 :DEPENDENTS NIL)
              #S(PSTRUCT
                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("DNI")
                 :DEPENDENTS NIL))))

(defparameter y2
 '#S(PSTRUCT
 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Sfin")
 :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Ext" "NP" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "S"
                                  "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                 :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON"
                                                  "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S"
                                                  "Sin1" "1st" "Sin"
                                                  "NomC")
                                 :DEPENDENTS NIL)))
              #S(PSTRUCT
                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Plu" "Sin2" "Sin3" "Sin1" "Pres" "V"
                                  "Trans_V" "TransComp_V" "Intrans_V"  
                                  "Ditrans_V" "Inf" "X")   ;;   <=== "X" to make them different 
                 :DEPENDENTS NIL)
              #S(PSTRUCT
                 :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("DNI")
                 :DEPENDENTS NIL))))

;; Here's the log.... 

    * (compare-pstructs x2 y2)

    "P1" 
#S(PSTRUCT
   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Sfin")
   :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Ext" "NP" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "S"
                                    "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                   :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON"
                                                    "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S"
                                                    "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                                   :DEPENDENTS NIL)))
                #S(PSTRUCT
                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Plu" "Sin2" "Sin3" "Sin1" "Pres" "V"
                                    "Trans_V" "TransComp_V" "Intrans_V"
                                    "Ditrans_V" "Inf")
                   :DEPENDENTS NIL)
                #S(PSTRUCT :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("DNI") :DEPENDENTS NIL))) 
"P2" 
#S(PSTRUCT
   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Sfin")
   :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Ext" "NP" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "S"
                                    "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                   :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON"
                                                    "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S"
                                                    "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                                   :DEPENDENTS NIL)))
                #S(PSTRUCT
                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Plu" "Sin2" "Sin3" "Sin1" "Pres" "V"
                                    "Trans_V" "TransComp_V" "Intrans_V"
                                    "Ditrans_V" "Inf" "X")
                   :DEPENDENTS NIL)
                #S(PSTRUCT :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("DNI") :DEPENDENTS NIL))) 
"idx before compare pstructs:" 
0 
"P1" 
#S(PSTRUCT
   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Ext" "NP" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "S" "Sin1" "1st" "Sin"
                    "NomC")
   :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S"
                                    "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                   :DEPENDENTS NIL))) 
"P2" 
#S(PSTRUCT
   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("Ext" "NP" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "S" "Sin1" "1st" "Sin"
                    "NomC")
   :DEPENDENTS (#S(PSTRUCT
                   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S"
                                    "Sin1" "1st" "Sin" "NomC")
                   :DEPENDENTS NIL))) 
"idx before compare pstructs:" 
0 
"P1" 
#S(PSTRUCT
   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S" "Sin1" "1st"
                    "Sin" "NomC")
   :DEPENDENTS NIL) 
"P2" 
#S(PSTRUCT
   :SYNTACTIC-INFO ("PRON" "Pron_PRON" "Pers_PRON" "Sin1" "S" "Sin1" "1st"
                    "Sin" "NomC")
   :DEPENDENTS NIL) 
"Added one to idx:" 
1 
"Added one to idx:"    <== See how the loop keeps iterating
2 
T
*
```

Comment: You might need something like `(declaim (optimize (debug 0) (safety 0) (speed 3))) ` to get TCO according to [this page](https://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html#sec-2-2) If this doesn't work try reducing your code so it' sstill shows the bug, but without everything else and post it.

Comment: This guy (who appears to be a genius) put together a library to adjust optimization to allow tail recursion in a couple of implementations of lisp: https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/frideau/ptc   Of course, it doesn't help, so maybe something else is up.  I'm working on a distilled version of the code.

Comment: Well, only SBCL and Clozure are supported and SBCL does it with `(declaim (optimize (debug 0) (safety 0) (speed 3)))`.

Comment: "only the code in the loop below the callback to bar" - So the call to `BAR` is not in tail position? In that case TCO shouldn't matter. You should post an example to demonstrate the problem. Seems more likely to be a logic error in your program, rather than SBCL doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `DEFPARAMETER` inside functions. It defines a global variable, which messes up your logic in `COMPARE-PARSES` since the recursive calls will use the same variables.

Your code is rather unidiomatic Lisp. You shouldn't use `IF`s and `RETURN-FROM` like that. Structure the functions into single expressions instead.

```
(defstruct pstruct
  ;; Instead of comments to say what type these are,
  ;; you could use code to tell it.
  (syntactic-info nil :type list)
  (dependents nil :type list))

;; Since the functions call each other, it's better to declare
;; their ftypes beforehand.
(declaim (ftype (function (list list) boolean) compare-parses)
         (ftype (function (pstruct pstruct) boolean) pstruct=))

(defun compare-parses (p1t p2t)
  (and (= (length p1t)
          (length p2t))
       (every #'pstruct= p1t p2t)))

(defun pstruct= (p1 p2)
  (and (equal (pstruct-syntactic-info p1)
              (pstruct-syntactic-info p2))
       (compare-parses (pstruct-dependents p1)
                       (pstruct-dependents p2))))
```

Common Lisp also provides some debugging tools, so you don't need to `PRINT` things. In this case you can use [`TRACE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tracec.htm)

```
CL-USER> (trace compare-parses pstruct=)
CL-USER> (pstruct= *x2* *y2*)
... Prints the trace ...
CL-USER> (untrace compare-parses pstruct=)
```

If you're using Emacs and Slime/Sly, you can also use the [trace dialog](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/SLIME-Trace-Dialog.html#SLIME-Trace-Dialog) for a bit nicer interface.

Also see [`BREAK`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_break.htm), [`INSPECT`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_inspec.htm), [`STEP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_step.htm) and the Slime equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the expert above came up with a solution to my problem.  I did make a big mistake using defparameter.  I did this here to get rid of the SBCL warnings, and since the HyperSpec said: "defparameter and defvar normally appear as a top level form, but it is meaningful for them to appear as non-top-level forms."

I took this to mean that it would maintain variables at local scope, but this is not true!!  Ouch.  Anyway, the code didn't work before adding the defparameter macro nor after removing it.

One other mistake seems to be thinking that stretching the code out farther and farther during the debugging process until you end up with something that looks and executes like (ugh) Pascal or Python doesn't help.  I am speculating that the optimizer has been hard-coded to expect program flow to be a particular way, and may be unpredictable if code is intentionally inefficient.

My original code was more condensed, but though logically identical, I couldn't get it to work.  Of course, at my current level of skill with Lisp I never would have guessed how to condense the code down as far as the expert above did... I mean, "every"?  I never knew there was a built-in for that!!